# Maintaining co-relation Id

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

I am working on a system design. I have implemented multiple layers in my application where the web layer calls the business layer and business layer call the data layer.

I want to keep a common co-relation id for every call, so that I can log the input to any method and in case of any error, the exception can be logged into database using the same co-relation id and finally need to show the co-relation id to the users screen in case of any error.

I have implemented this using WCF service where I take the message id as the co-relational id and use it throughout the request life cycle. But I am not sure how to implement this with normal libraries. I don’t want to pass the co-relation id on every method as parameter or a parameter to the constructer of every class.

Can anyone point me to any article or implementation approach for this.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a singleton class object instance to hold the co-relation id for a particular call and dispose the object at the end of the retrieval of data from Database(end of call).

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more information about how your layers are structured.

That said, if all your business services are stateless, one can assume you instantiate for each request a new `XXXService` class (say for example `CustomerService`).

What you could then do is to pass your correlation ID to every service class you instantiate, for example using a dependency injection framework. So inside the `CustomerService` class, you could have access to the correlation ID that was generated for your request.

Answer (score 0):

I would have all my domain services' methods require an `executionContext` parameter (could be a `Dictionary<string, object>` or a domain class if you want). This allows for more extensibility as the requirements change in the future.